# Is there a relationship between the elevation/altitude of a city and its GDP?

Tags: gdp

A year or two ago, I recall watching a YouTube video that looked at the GDP of various cities and argued that there was a weak positive correlation between their elevation and their GDP. I can't find the video again and I haven't been able to find many supporting documents for this - I did find one about China but not the world at large. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11629-017-4393-0

Has anyone seen this argument and know the details?

Comment: I've heard of examples of different altitudes affecting quality of natural resources such as metals and minerals, might be worth looking into that.

Comment: Not familiar with this literature, but one more reason off the top of my head is access to seaports which would help a city grow in the 18th–19th centuries.

Comment: I've not seen the argument, but I would suggest there's a range of elevations for which this relationship is positive, outside of which it may be flat or negative.  And, there's probably a "third thing" that depends on elevation and is the true explanatory mechanism - such as the ideas the others have noted.